# Where is boost::filesystem::last_write_time?

Tags: c++, boost

This is the linker error I'm getting.  All the rest of my boost::filesystem things are resolving.  I'm not understanding why this one does not.  I thought it was a problem with boost 1.40, so I upgraded to 1.44 and the problem remains.  I'm using `#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3` but I see no mention of last_write_time not being provided in that case.  It seems the underlying implementation is missing, even though the api portion is present.

```
1>TestPruner.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem3::detail::last_write_time(class boost::filesystem3::path const &,long,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?last_write_time@detail@filesystem3@boost@@YAXABVpath@23@JPAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::filesystem3::last_write_time(class boost::filesystem3::path const &,long)" (?last_write_time@filesystem3@boost@@YAXABVpath@12@J@Z)
```

Oh yea, using Windows VS2008.

The code involved is:

```
time_t curTime = time(NULL);
bfs::last_write_time(bfs::path("TestData/PruneTest/completed/Batch001.DAT"), curTime);
```

Anyone else run into this?

And it happens with `#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2` as well.  The Boost libraries I'm using are from boostpro (prebuilt, yea, I'm lazy)

```
2>TestPruner.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_code __cdecl boost::filesystem2::detail::last_write_time_api(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,long)" (?last_write_time_api@detail@filesystem2@boost@@YA?AVerror_code@system@3@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@J@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::filesystem2::last_write_time<class boost::filesystem2::basic_path<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct boost::filesystem2::path_traits> >(class boost::filesystem2::basic_path<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct boost::filesystem2::path_traits> const &,long)" (??$last_write_time@V?$basic_path@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@Upath_traits@filesystem2@boost@@@filesystem2@boost@@@filesystem2@boost@@YAXABV?$basic_path@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@Upath_traits@filesystem2@boost@@@01@J@Z)
```

From /versbose:lib

```
Searching e:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\lib\libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_44.lib:
Searching e:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\lib\libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-gd-1_44.lib:
```

Comment: Are you linking to the 1.44 builds or the 1.40 builds?

Comment: Linking with 1.44, it appears to be broken in both though, I only upgraded to 1.44 after the link failed in 1.40, but I did fix the library paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the problem is as simple as it is obtuse.  In VS2008 and above time_t is 64 bits, unless you `#define _USE_32_BIT_TIME_T`.  The boost libraries are compiled without this definition and therefore time_t is 64 bits for them.  My project due to some legacy issues does define _USE_32_BIT_TIME_T and therefore generates the API with a 32 bit time.

If you build a project that doesn't use 32 bit time, it works as expected.

I'm glad the C++ guys were smart enough to push the call signature into the linker with name mangling.  If they hadn't done that, I'd still be wondering what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is so much a problem with the function as with the function arguments.  Looking through the boost::filesystem api, I couldn't find a last_write_detail function with both Path and time arguments, only a Path argument.  On the other hand I did find

```
last_write_time_api( const std::string & ph, std::time_t new_value );
```

as opposed to

```
BOOST_FS_FUNC(std::time_t) last_write_time( const Path & ph )
```

So maybe the error is because the linker can't find a version of the function with the right signature, and you should be using last_write_time_api instead?

Comment: I see docs for it here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#last_write_time